# GLSurfaceview how to add color in captured x, y position android

Tags: android, arcore, android-camera2

I have a android.opengl.GLSurfaceView in a ARCore project.

I want to draw the color(overlay) in captured x,y positions.

See the below screenshot exactly what I needed.

Greened area was already captured area and next one is going to capture image.

[image]